# How to overriede logoutOtherDevices() function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, overriding, logout

I face some problem to override function in Laravel. This is the logoutOtherDevices function in the vendor folder (Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard) in laravel. I want to pass a `$user_name` in this function to allow some user can multiple login.

```
public function logoutOtherDevices($password, $user_name, $attribute = 'password')
        {
            if (! $this->user() || $this->user()->user_name == $user_name) {
                return;
            }
    
            $result = tap($this->user()->forceFill([
                $attribute => Hash::make($password),
            ]))->save();
    
            $this->queueRecallerCookie($this->user());
    
            return $result;
        }
```

But since this is in the vendor folder, so i not willing to edit code in the core file.

Can some one give me some guidance to override this function in LoginController?

Because I plan to add some condition to end the user session on other device.

Appreciate all the suggestion and guidance.

Comment: The `SessionGuard` is macroable, you can add methods at run time to it, and  the `LoginController` is yours so you can adjust what the `LoginController` is calling potentially

Comment: maybe you can elaborate on these conditions and what you are trying to do that is different

Comment: @lagbox thanks for you reply bro, i was try to make a condition that pass $user_name in that function to make some user allow to multiple login.

Comment: you can macro your own version of that method how you want it, then call your version from the LoginController